# How do I get yum to see updates to a local repo without cleaning cache?

Tags: rpm, yum, repository

I have set up a local yum repository which I use to install test builds. For the testing purposes, my packages are versioned by `<svn version number>.<date>.<time>` (e.g. `12345.20110908.150404`

The trouble is, once I make a new RPM, copy it to the repository directory and run `createrepo $REPO_DIR`, yum does not see the new RPM as being available.

```
$ cd $REPO_DIR
$ ls -1
repodata
package-12345.20110908.150404-1.x86_64.rpm
package-12345.20110908.174329-1.x86_64.rpm

$ createrepo .
# ...snip...

$ rpm -q package
package-12345.20110908.150404-1.x86_64

$ yum list --showduplicates package
Installed Packages
package.x86_64    12345.20110908.150404-1    @repo
Available Packages
package.x86_64    12345.20110908.150404-1    repo
```

I can see the updates and grab them if I run `yum clean all` and then re-fetch the metadata, but I think this just means I need to be doing something else from the repo, as I don't have to do that for other yum repos.

How do I need to set up my local repository so that I only need to run `yum update` from the client without having to clean my yum cache?

Answer (score 26):

You can run "yum clean expire-cache" which is much more efficient way to tell yum to check the repos. ... the other thing to do would be to change the metadata_expire value for the local repo. (see man yum.conf).

Comment: Is there a way to expire-cache only specific repository?

Comment: The only easy way to do that is --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=myrepo,otherrepo ... although you can create an alias if it's something you'll do a lot.

Answer (score 11):

Try adding following line in /etc/yum.conf on Yum clients:

> metadata_expire=1m

Following command shows you more info:

> man yum.conf

FYI. CentOS 5 has the parameter commented out.  CentOS 6.2 has 90m for the value.

Comment: This is somewhat old, but I just ran into this. You can set this value for a single repository by editing the /etc/yum.repos.d/my.repo file.

Answer (score 3):

`yum clean metadata` cleans up just the cached names and such, after which yum reloads its idea of what is available.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue, try:

> yum clean all

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I believe he was looking for an alternative method where he didn't have to clear the cache.

Comment: god you're so right :|

Answer (score 0):

yum's --enablerepo=localrpmrepo is the option you are after. so

```
yum --enablerepo=localrpmrepo clean metadata
```

replace localrpmrepo with your repos name

Comment: Nope, in this case, the problem is certainly that it thinks the cache is still valid and doesn't check for updates.

Comment: I was able to update just one repository using this statement and another one: `yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=epel clean metadata -q; yum check-update --disablrepo=* --enablerepo=epel -q`. I'll just make a bash function and be done with it!